# PHP/ARRAYS/API/JSON - I dont understand why I dont get any results

Tags: php, arrays

So Ive got this array (see below) that I got by getting the file_contents of the API URL and then doing a json_decode($url,true) on the results to get an array.

```
Array ( [0] => 
        Array ( 
            [Id] => 1104 
            [Key] => 100-og 
            [Name] => $100 OG 
            [Category] => Hybrid 
            [Symbol] => 100 
            [Abstract] => 
            [Url] => http://www.leafly.com/hybrid/100-og 
            [DetailUrl] => http://www.leafly.com/api/details/100-og 
            [RateUrl] => http://www.leafly.com/me/create/100-og 
            [Rating] => 8.2 
            [TopEffect] => Euphoric 
            [TopMedical] => Stress 
            [TopActivity] => Relax at home ) 
        )
```

So the array is in a variable called $strain_data and when I try and access the array, say with something like: echo $strain_data['name']; I get errors like this:

> Notice: Undefined index: name

The only thing I see to be able to do is count how many items there are total ($strain_total = count($strain_data);) which says there are 545.

I really dont get it. If you can help explain this, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: It's an array of arrays, so you need `$strain_data[0]['Name']`.

Answer (score 7):

Case sensitivity critically hits you. - it's `Name` not `name`. Besides that, you forgot `[0]` since you have an array of arrays.

Try `$strain_data[0]['Name']`

Comment: Thank you! I had tried ['0'] but never [0].

Answer (score 0):

this is an associative array . Try this

```
$strain_data[0]['Name'];
```

Comment: Actually, the answer you've given indicates it's *not* an associative array.  (The `[0]` is obviously a numerical, and almost certainly sequential, index.)  Now, each *element* is an associative array...but the OP already had half a clue about that, as evidenced by the attempts to get `['name']`, so i don't get the reason behind saying "this is an associative array".